Alter tablespace of existing database in Postgresql
I have a database located in default tablespace named "pg_default". Due to space limit in directory,  I need to alter tablespace of my database to new custom tablespace. How I can do that ? Postgresql with version 14
I created new tablespace in different directory with enough space. so that database can be moved.

Is there some information missing from the official docs? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdatabase.html

These days, the best practice is to extend the file system with the default tablespace.
